# How can I invoke multiple web services using JAXB in Spring?

Tags: spring, webservice-client

I'm building an application with Spring MVC (3.2). This application need to invoke to 2 web services. It's ok when I invoke each service separately. However, it's not work when I call both. My application config file:

```
<bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11" />
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- The first service-->
<bean id="local" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"
    p:contextPath="com.ws" />
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="local" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="local" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://localhost:9999/ws/ProcessService" />
</bean>
<!-- The second service-->
<bean id="preconvert" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"
    p:contextPath="com.ws.preprocess" />

<bean id="wstemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="preconvert" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="preconvert" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://localhost:9999/jod/PreProcessService" />
</bean>
```

Help me please! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi chicky I solved the problem

Beans XML

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate1" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller1"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller1"/>
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL"/>
</bean>

<bean id="webServiceTemplate2" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller2"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller2"/>
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL"/>
</bean>
```

webServiceTemplate1 service

```
@Autowired
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate1;

@Override
public double obtenerCambio(String from, String to) {               

    ConversionRate conversionRate = new ObjectFactory().createConversionRate();
    conversionRate.setFromCurrency(Currency.fromValue(from));
    conversionRate.setToCurrency(Currency.fromValue(to));

    ConversionRateResponse conversionRateResponse = (ConversionRateResponse) webServiceTemplate1.marshalSendAndReceive(conversionRate);     
    return conversionRateResponse.getConversionRateResult();
}
```

And webServiceTemplate2

```
@Autowired
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate2;

@Override
public String obtenerConversion(String celcius) {

    CelsiusToFahrenheit celsiusToFahrenheit = new ObjectFactory().createCelsiusToFahrenheit();
    celsiusToFahrenheit.setCelsius(celcius);

    CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse response = (CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse) webServiceTemplate2.marshalSendAndReceive(celsiusToFahrenheit);
    return response.getCelsiusToFahrenheitResult();     
}
```